# Filtering/Selecting array values from index in Json in groovy

Tags: arrays, arraylist, groovy, katalon-studio, groovy-console

Trying to filter selective index. Fieldid values changes with every build, What do not change is `fieldName": "TX.Sessionval.cost"`. Need to filter out the whole `stringval` and save into variable

```
fieldName": "TX.Sessionval.cost"
```

```
[
  {
   "Fieldid": "Fieldid/112",
    "fieldName": "TX.Sessionval.cost",
    "stringval": "jklah-dw-4c8d-8320-das313s3ASsda|000725N8WuUrfwAS7alP|banker_name"
  }
]
```

tried `def slurper = new JsonSlurper() def result = slurper.parseText(response.getResponseBodyContent()) def newf = result.findAll { it.contains("TX.Sessionval.cost") }` getting groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.LinkedHashMap$Entry.contains()

in Postman locator works fine

```
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("Stdid", jsonData.newFields[112].stringValue)
```

Comment: The error is due to iterating over a map.  Most likely `result` does not contain, what you think it contains (e.g. the json is not an array but an object at top level).

Comment: result do have the ` "Fieldid": "Fieldid/112", "fieldName": "TX.Sessionval.cost", "stringval": "jklah-dw-4c8d-8320-das313s3ASsda|000725N8WuUrfwAS7alP|banker_name" ` under newFields[112] but it changed every time so instead this, need to search whole JSON output with katalon.

Comment: so, your `result` contains just one map without wrapping array. truthfully i cant understand what you want to achieve.. but if you want to remove all keys from map where value does not contain 'TX...' : `result.findAll{ ! it.value.contains("TX.Sessionval.cost") }`

Comment: Your example JSON is a **map** inside a **list**.  And the error you are getting is that an element of `result` is a **map entry** - so clearly there is a discrepancy between the JSON you are sharing and JSON you are actually reading.

Comment: JSON result is huge, just looking out the solution based on what i am using for `postman.setEnvironmentVariable("Stdid", jsonData.newFields[112].stringValue)` but since the value gets changed everytime like Fieldid": "Fieldid/112, Fieldid": "Fieldid/123, Fieldid": "Fieldid/129 then have to manually edit it every time rather filtering to specific search  When fieldName": "TX.Sessionval.cost" is this print the stringvalue

Comment: If you reduce your problem to something, that no longer represents your
actual problem, then you wont get any good answers because they will
answer the wrong question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works with me `result.newFields.findAll { Map map ->   map.get("fieldName").contains("TX.Sessionval.cost") }?.stringValue`

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON in your question is wrong.  Extrapolating from your working
code, this should work:

```
result.newFields.find{ it.fieldName == "TX.Sessionval.cost" }?.stringValue
```

Comment: @cfick, what to update in question to be more meaningful, update the same

Comment: console gives me null when printed, just to add when checked Json path it gives me x.newFields[112].stringValue.

Comment: customFields(filter((a)==a.fieldName=='TX.Sessionval.cost')[0].stringValue)) this works in postman

Comment: First `newFields` worked and now `customFields` works... have you tried applying that to my answer?

Comment: Yes your solution works in postman. but it doesn't works with groovy `newFields` ignore customfield sorry.

Comment: This works with me `result.newFields.findAll { Map map ->
 map.get("fieldName").contains("TX.Sessionval.cost") }?.stringValue`